# Error 0x80004003 while loading package file...Invalid pointer

Tags: ssis

So I've been trying to test an SSIS parent package that was developed on my C: drive on my D: drive, which is just a partition on my hard drive with a directory structure that is setup to mimic our other environments. This isn't something new, as I've been able to test packages on D before deploying to the Int, Cert, and Prod environments.

In any case, the parent and individual children packages work fine on C, but when I copy the corresponding .dtsx package files onto the D drive, I'm receiving the Error `0x80004003` while loading package file "C:\tfs_ses|Dev|code\ssis\SES ETL\SES ETL"Package Name.dtsx"...Invalid pointer. I even tried changing the individual connection managers to point to the corresponding .dtsx files on D, as they were copied there from C, but still received this Invalid pointer error. The configuration file has the following amongst its other values: `"DMConfig_PackageFilePath"="D:\SFAS\SSIS\SESDatamart\packages"`and `"SESDM_dtsConfigPath"="D:\SFAS\SSIS\SESDatamart\config"`. I've also ensured that the connection manager property of Expression for ConnectionString shows as: `@[User::PackageFilePath] + "Extract_PCMPolicy.dtsx`.

I'm unsure why I'm getting this error. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

first of all try to create a simple package on drive `D` to check if there is a problem loading it.

Comment: Thanks, mhd swe....the child package on D does successfully run. Any additional suggestions, please?

Comment: check the value of variable `PackageFilePath` and check if it is reading from an `expression` or not